# heapster-controller.yaml error -choose one of: [heapster eventer heapster-nanny eventer-nanny]

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb, grafana, heapster

Trying to deploy `heapster-controller` to get Heapster + Graphana + InfluxDB working for Kubernetes. Getting error messages while trying ot deploy using heapster-controller.yaml file:

**heapster-controller.yaml**

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: heapster-v1.1.0-beta1
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: heapster
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: heapster
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: heapster
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/google_containers/heapster:v1.1.0-beta1
          name: heapster
          resources:
            # keep request = limit to keep this container in guaranteed class
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 200m 
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 200m 
          command:
            - /heapster
            - --source=kubernetes.summary_api:''
            - --sink=influxdb:http://monitoring-influxdb:8086
            - --metric_resolution=60s
        - image: gcr.io/google_containers/heapster:v1.1.0-beta1
          name: eventer
          resources:
            # keep request = limit to keep this container in guaranteed class
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 200m 
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory:  200m
          command:
            - /eventer
            - --source=kubernetes:''
            - --sink=influxdb:http://monitoring-influxdb:8086
        - image: gcr.io/google_containers/addon-resizer:1.0
          name: heapster-nanny
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 100Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 100Mi
          env:
            - name: MY_POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          command:
            - /pod_nanny
            - --cpu=100m
            - --extra-cpu=0m
            - --memory=200
            - --extra-memory=200Mi
            - --threshold=5
            - --deployment=heapster-v1.1.0-beta1
            - --container=heapster
            - --poll-period=300000
        - image: gcr.io/google_containers/addon-resizer:1.0
          name: eventer-nanny
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 100Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 100Mi
          env:
            - name: MY_POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          command:
            - /pod_nanny
            - --cpu=100m
            - --extra-cpu=0m
            - --memory=200
            - --extra-memory=200Ki
            - --threshold=5
            - --deployment=heapster-v1.1.0-beta1
            - --container=eventer
            - --poll-period=300000`

Deployment goes through, but then I get error:

`[root@node236 influxdb]# kubectl get pods -o wide --namespace=kube-system
NAME                                     READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE       NODE
heapster-v1.1.0-beta1-3082378092-t6inb   2/4       RunContainerError   0          1m        node262.local.net
[root@node236 influxdb]#`

Display log for the failed container:

`[root@node236 influxdb]# kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system heapster-v1.1.0-beta1-3082378092-t6inb
Error from server: a container name must be specified for pod heapster-v1.1.0-beta1-3082378092-t6inb, choose one of: [heapster eventer heapster-nanny eventer-nanny]
[root@node236 influxdb]#`

Where am I possibly going wrong ?

Any feedback appreaciated!!

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is `kubectl logs <pod> <container>`.

In your example, `kubectl logs heapster-v1.1.0-beta1-3082378092-t6inb heapster --namespace=kube-system` will show the logs of the "heapster" container within the named pod.

Comment: Use `kubectl describe pod ...` to find out more about which container might be having an issue.

Comment: There are multiple containers in the Heapster pod. To get the logs from the pod, you need to specify which container you want to look at. The correct syntax is `kubectl logs [-f] [-p] POD [-c CONTAINER] [flags]`. You'll also want to add the `-p` to access the logs from the previous container (which has terminated) if none of the container is not currently running.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the feedback. I think my problem lies around tls-certs. Need to dig deeper.

Thanks so much yet again!!